# Laravel 9.x msg 403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Eu gostaria de saber, o laravel por padrao quando faz um requisicao de rota que nao esta autorizada ele redireciona para a rota login certo? o meu nao.

Estou usando o middware auth.

ex: no controller assim

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index']);
    }


public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('admin');
```

na rota assim:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::prefix('/app')->group(function(){


    Route::resource('/visitantes','App\Http\Controllers\VisitanteController');
    
});
```

contudo quando tento acessar uma rota NÃO logado ex: http://127.0.0.1:8090/app/visitantes

ela me retora a pagina com msg:
403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.

Saberiam me informar como posso fazer essa pagina nao seja apresentada e sim redirecione para a rota login?

ultima coisa, meu middleware authenticate.php esta assim:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi meu problema substituindo isso:

```
   $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index']);
```

Por isso :

```
   $this->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Para utilizares a autenticação do Laravel, deves atribuir o middleware à rota que pretendes autorizar.

```php
Route::resource('/visitantes','App\Http\Controllers\VisitanteController')->middleware('auth');
```

Ao chamares `$this->authorize('admin')` no método `VisitanteController::index()`, é o mesmo que chamares `Gate::authorize('admin')`, e este método não se relaciona com o middleware de autenticação.

As Gates são para controlar autorização e, neste caso específico, o método [authorize](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#authorizing-or-throwing-exceptions) verifica se o utilizador tem autorização para aceder à habilidade `admin`. Se não tiver, é emita uma exceção do tipo `AuthorizationException` que, por sua vez, é convertida numa resposta com o código 403.